# How to prevent xUnit from logging when use it from `dotnet test`?

Tags: xunit, githooks, xunit.net, .net-6.0, xunit2

It should be simple, but I am not able to make it.

Setup

1. .NET 6 class library
2. xUnit 2.4.1 as a test framework

Everything is nice.

I am trying to execute all my unit tests before committing. 
If any unit test failed I will prevent the commit. 
I am doing this in the `pre-commit` git hook. 
And I was able to make it with this code (inside the `pre-commit` hook)

```
if ! dotnet test --nologo --verbosity q > buildoutput.txt
then
  echo "Test failed"
  exit 1
fi

exit 0
```

everything is fine and good, I have a very small problem 
I do not want the [xUnit.net] logs from showing its log in the Git panel

[image]

I just want to show a simple message that 'Test failed'

**How can I prevent the xUnit package from showing those messages?**

Comment: use `>&` instead of `>` for redirection perhaps?

Comment: @AnthonySottile you are my hero, post this as an answer and I will accept and upvote it, Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it appears the output is coming from `stderr`

in your command you're only piping stdout to the file (`>`):

```sh
if ! dotnet test --nologo --verbosity q > buildoutput.txt
```

you can additionally pipe stderr by using `>&` (or `> 2>&1` for slightly more compatibility):

```sh
if ! dotnet test --nologo --verbosity q >& buildoutput.txt
```